# How to find what type of timestamp my application is using?

Tags: time, timestamp, unix-timestamp, android-sensors

I'm using a sensor logging application, which outputs sensor values, alongside with a timestamp. But different sensors give different timestamps.

Take a look at these two rows, measured at the same time :

```
MMC328X|[-101.5625,92.96875,63.867188]|92997954418000
GPS|29.0479791|41.0857844|0|1395061411822
```

the first one has a timestamp `92997954418000`, and the other one has `1395061411822`. I think the second one is a Unix Timestamp, but what is the first one? Is this a different standard for timestamps?

And how to convert them to each other?

**How to convert the first value to a unix timestamp?**

Thanks for any help!

### Edit:

Some details about my data (thousands of rows like these).

I analyzed the difference between GPS and MMC328X rows, the GPS rows usually have 1000. So I guess this means that my GPS sensor logged values every one second.

Whereas, the MMC rows have a difference of 0.5e6 = 500000. But I'm fairly sure that the sensor frequency is not 500 seconds..

Comment: yes, the second value looks like milliseconds since epoch: `2014-03-17 13:03:31.822`

Comment: wild guess: the first one might be the result of `System.nanoTime()` (only two values make sense to get elapsed nanoseconds).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks. But I still don't understand what is the first value. And the thing I really need is, how to convert it to a unix timestamp? I found this site: http://www.epochconverter.com/ but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: To check whether my guess about the first value is correct, you need at least *two* values (at different times)

Comment: I have thousands of them. But the problem is, they (the MMC328X rows) are 14-digit. If this was a millisecond since some epoch, it should be 13-digit like the GPS (2nd) value in my question. Am I wrong ?

Comment: [my guess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590409/how-to-find-what-type-of-timestamp-my-application-is-using#comment34397765_22590409) is it is a value in nanoseconds and it is relative time (there is no epoch). You could use them to find out how many nanoseconds elapsed between two entries

Comment: hmm. so it is not the time since T0 , but the time since the last entry ? Then these are too big. When I multiply by 1e-9, I get around 90000. They are certainly not 90000 seconds apart. multiplying by e-14 gives something like 0.9. But a sensitivity of 1e-14? Is this possible ?

Comment: and by looking at the data, the values are constantly increasing. So they should be the time relative to a fixed time.

Comment: the **difference** between values is significant. Take two entries, subtract two (14-digit) values: the difference is number of nanoseconds. There is no epoch means that the values might start at computer start up, or at the process start up, etc

Comment: the difference between two values is around 5e7 = 50000000.

Comment: Are 0.05 seconds a reasonable time delay between entries?

Comment: I think so. Now I'm testing the sensor frequency, and it is like 16 entries per second, so 0.06 is pretty close. So does this mean it is the nanoseconds since some time ?

Comment: The strange thing is, now it (MMC) gives 5019316773000, a 13-digit timestamp. It seems like 83 minutes. I'm really confused..

Comment: It seems I can't express it clearly. It doesn't make sense to talk about a *single* value, only the difference matters. Without the second number, `5019316773000` doesn't mean anything. See [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Comment: No I got you, but I think we agreed that the values are not the time since last entry, but a timestamp with respect to a different epoch. Because if it was the first case, the values should be similar. But they are increasing constantly.

Comment: **yes**: *"the values are not the time since last entry"*. **No**: there is no epoch, [read the docs I've linked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). The values are increasing because they have the same origin time if they are generated by the same jvm instance.